# Make the grouped by rows a part of the data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

The following code results in the following output \

mean = df.groupby("Group").mean()[image]

How can I make so the 'Group' column is part of the data frame rather than a simple index aka [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the parameter "as_index" in the groupby function

```
mean = df.groupby("Group", as_index = False).mean()
```